# How to implement Go concurrent map or slice for managing in-use resources faster?

Tags: go, concurrency

Image you have a struct that represents a resource that only one user can access at a time. Might look something like this:

```golang
type Resource struct{
    InUse bool//or int32/int64 is you want to use atomics
    Resource string //parameters that map to the resource, think `/dev/chardeviceXXX`
}
```

There are a finite number of these resources and users will request access to them randomly and concurrently so you package them in a manager

```golang
type ResourceManager struct{
    Resources []*Resource //or a map 
}
```

I am trying to figure out the optimal, safe way for the manager to create a function `func (m *ResourceManager)GetUnusedResouce()(*Resouce,error)` that will:

- Iterate though all the resources until one that is not InUse is found
- Mark it as InUse and return the *Resouce to the calling context/goroutine
- I'd lock to avoid any system level locking (flock) and do this all in Go
- There also needs to be a function to mark the Resouce are no longer in Use

Right now I use a mutex in the manager to lock access as I iterate through the entire slice. It is safe, but I am hoping to speed this up by being able to search for an used resource concurrently and handle two goroutines trying to mark the same resource as InUse.

#### Update

I am specifically wondering if making the Resource `InUse` field an `int64` and then using `atomic.CompareAndSwapInt64` would allow the Resource manager to lock right when it found an unused resource:

```golang
func (m *ResourceManager)GetUnusedResouce()(*Resouce,error){
    for i := range Resources{
        if atomic.CompareAndSwapInt64(&Resouces[i].InUse,1){
            return Resouces[i],nil
        }
    }
    return nil, errors.New("all resouces in use")
}
```

Any unit tests to better test this would also be appreciated.

Comment: you might want separate stores for resources in use (perhaps identified by the handle that will be used for freeing) and free resources.

Comment: If the only access to the manager and resources is what's described here, then keep a mutex protected singly linked list of free resources in the manager.  GetUnusedResource takes the first resource from the list.  ReleaseResource adds the resource to the beginning of the list.

Comment: @CeriseLimón that is definitely the safe way of doing it, but someone with a deeper knowledge of Go's concurrency model may be able to lock upon !InUse detection, using something like `atomic.CompareAndSwapInt`

Comment: I suggest to go with what @cerise-limón proposed: _if_ you need someone else's insight on whether an atomic operation would work or not, you do not need atomic operations _this time:_ as a programmer, your foremost concern should be making your code correct; you could make it faster (and still correct) once you have _solid_ knowledge of the relevant concepts.

Comment: @kostix question has been updated to reflect the desire to look at more technical and faster options as I already have a safe option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GetUnusedResouce` function in the question can potentially execute compare and swap operations for all resources.  Depending on the number of resources and the application access pattern, it can be quicker to execute a small number of operations protected by a mutex.

Use a singly linked list to implement fast get and put operations.

```
type Resource struct {
    next     *Resource
    Resource string
}

type ResourceManager struct {
    free *Resource
    mu   sync.Mutex
}

// Get gets a free resource from the manager or returns
// nil when the manager is empty.
func (m *ResourceManager) Get() *Resource {
    m.mu.Lock()
    defer m.mu.Unlock()
    result := m.free
    if m.free != nil {
        m.free = m.free.next
    }
    return result
}

// Put returns a resource to the pool.
func (m *ResourceManager) Put(r *Resource) {
    m.mu.Lock()
    defer m.mu.Unlock()
    r.next = m.free
    m.free = r
}
```

Here's an example use in a test:

```
func TestResourceManager(t *testing.T) {

    // Add free resources to a manager.
    var m ResourceManager
    m.Put(&Resource{Resource: "/dev/a"})
    m.Put(&Resource{Resource: "/dev/b"})

    // Test that we can get all resources from the pool.

    ra := m.Get()
    rb := m.Get()
    if ra.Resource > rb.Resource {
        // Sort ra, rb to make test independent of order.
        ra, rb = rb, ra
    }
    if ra == nil || ra.Resource != "/dev/a" {
        t.Errorf("ra is %v, want /dev/a", ra)
    }
    if rb == nil || rb.Resource != "/dev/b" {
        t.Errorf("rb is %v, want /dev/b", rb)
    }

    // Check for empty pool.

    r := m.Get()
    if r != nil {
        t.Errorf("r is %v, want nil", r)
    }

    // Return one resource and try again.

    m.Put(ra)
    ra = m.Get()
    if ra == nil || ra.Resource != "/dev/a" {
        t.Errorf("ra is %v, want /dev/a", ra)
    }
    r = m.Get()
    if r != nil {
        t.Errorf("r is %v, want nil", r)
    }

}
```

[Run the test on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/BAuCVrPW-mv).

Use a channel if there's a known reasonable bound on the number of resources.  This approach takes advantage of the runtime's highly optimized channel implementation.

```
type Resource struct {
    Resource string
}

type ResourceManager struct {
    free chan *Resource
}

// Get gets a free resource from the manager or returns
// nil when the manager is empty.
func (m *ResourceManager) Get() *Resource {
    select {
    case r := <-m.free:
        return r
    default:
        return nil
    }
}

// Put returns a resource to the pool.
func (m *ResourceManager) Put(r *Resource) {
    m.free <- r
}

// NewResourceManager returns a manager that can hold up to
// n free resources.
func NewResourceManager(n int) *ResourceManager {
    return &ResourceManager{free: make(chan *Resource, n)}
}
```

Test this implementation using the `TestResourceManager` function above, but replace `var m ResourceManager` with `m := NewResourceManager(4)`.

[Run the test on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8OpPYrDcsCQ).

Comment: The code is extremely readable too. I'll find time to benchmark all of these.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not a given resource is in-use is not a property of the `Resource` itself, but of the `ResourceManager`.

In fact, there is no need to keep track of in-use resources (unless you need to for some reason not mentioned in the question). An in-use resource can be simply put back into the pool when it is released.

Here's a possible implementation using channels. Not a single mutex, nor any atomic CAS needed.

```
package main

import (
    fmt "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Resource struct {
    Data string
}

type ResourceManager struct {
    resources []*Resource
    closeCh   chan struct{}
    acquireCh chan *Resource
    releaseCh chan *Resource
}

func NewResourceManager() *ResourceManager {
    r := &ResourceManager{
        closeCh:   make(chan struct{}),
        acquireCh: make(chan *Resource),
        releaseCh: make(chan *Resource),
    }
    go r.run()
    return r
}

func (r *ResourceManager) run() {
    defer close(r.acquireCh)
    for {
        if len(r.resources) > 0 {
            select {
            case r.acquireCh <- r.resources[len(r.resources)-1]:
                r.resources = r.resources[:len(r.resources)-1]
            case res := <-r.releaseCh:
                r.resources = append(r.resources, res)
            case <-r.closeCh:
                return
            }
        } else {
            select {
            case res := <-r.releaseCh:
                r.resources = append(r.resources, res)
            case <-r.closeCh:
                return
            }
        }
    }
}

func (r *ResourceManager) AcquireResource() *Resource {
    return <-r.acquireCh
}

func (r *ResourceManager) ReleaseResource(res *Resource) {
    r.releaseCh <- res
}

func (r *ResourceManager) Close() {
    close(r.closeCh)
}

// small demo below ...

func test(id int, r *ResourceManager) {
    for {
        res := r.AcquireResource()
        fmt.Printf("test %d: %s\n", id, res.Data)
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
        r.ReleaseResource(res)
    }
}

func main() {
    r := NewResourceManager()
    r.ReleaseResource(&Resource{"Resource A"}) // initial setup
    r.ReleaseResource(&Resource{"Resource B"}) // initial setup
    go test(1, r)
    go test(2, r)
    go test(3, r) // 3 consumers, but only 2 resources ...
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    r.Close()
}
```

Comment: I like the approach, but I think the channel overhead may slow down the solution. Let me benchmark and see how it compares to just a Mutex Lock.

Comment: Sure, would be interested to know how it compares. As for the updated question: yes, the CAS will work fine. A CAS is a CAS. The inefficiency with that solution lies in constantly iterating over in-use elements and in handling resource exhaustion efficiently.